# jQuery JSON ASP.NET MVC Access Object with Array List Properties?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, arrays, json

I have an object with 2 ArrayList properties.

```
public class TestDTO
{
    public ArrayList Test1 { get; set; }
    public ArrayList Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am returning the the object as JSON in my JsonResult Action.  The SUCCESS from my AJAX call looks like the following but it does not appear to be working.  What do I need to do to access the serialized array from the object?

```
 success: function(data) {

                    var counter = 1;
                    jQuery.each(data.Test1, function() {
                        $("#DataFields" + counter).val(this);
                        counter++;
                    });
                },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to see what the result looks like is to use Firebug in Mozilla. Or the stand-alone application Fiddler.

I think that the class wraps the whole object, so it should look something similar to this:

```
TestDTO {
   Test1 [
      "value", "value 1", "value 2"
   ],
   Test2 [
      "value", "value 1", "value 2"
   ]
}
```

If you'd like to access Test1 you'd write TestDTO.Test1. If you want the first value in Test1 you'd write TestDTO.Test1[0] and so on...

One way to get more control of the output is to use LINQ and select new:

```
select new {
   MyVariable = MyValue,
   AnotherVariable = AnotherValue
}
```

Now you know that "MyVariable" will be the JSON variable name as well.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following is useful?:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.Test1, function(i, item) {
        $('#DataFields' + i).val(item);
    });
}
```

Comment: That's nice and new to me. Ty :)

Answer (score 1):

When I get in to situations like this, I use firebug and break somewhere inside the success method. Then check out the actual structure of data and I'll bet it will be obvious.